# How can I pass an object to Url.Action as a RouteValueDictionary when I use the helper in a class?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

**Short Version:**
I have an extension method that extends MVC 5's UrlHelper helper method. I want to pass in (string action, string controller, object routeValues) to this method, and use Url.Action("action", "controller", routeValues) inside it. I get an `ArgumentNullException` for `routeCollection` when I do this. What is the correct way of doing this so I don't get this exception?

**Long version**
I have the following extension method:

```
public static string ActionToUrl(this UrlHelper url, string action, string controller, object routeValues)
    {
        Uri contextUri = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url;

        var relativeContentPath = url.Action(action, controller, routeValues);

        var baseUri = string.Format("{0}://{1}{2}", contextUri.Scheme,
           contextUri.Host, contextUri.Port == 80 ? string.Empty : ":" + contextUri.Port);

        return string.Format("{0}{1}", baseUri, VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute(relativeContentPath));
    }
```

The idea is, this method will return an absolute url path when used instead of the relative path that `Url.Action` returns.

However, I get an ArgumentNullException when I try using `Url.Action` inside this with the `RouteValueDictionary` overload:

> Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeCollection

I don't get this exception if I use the simple (action, controller) overload.

I also tried constructing the `RouteValueDictionary` with its `RouteValueDictionary(object routeValues)` constructor and then sending it to `Url.Action` like:

```
var routeValueDictionary = new RouteValueDictionary();

var relativeContentPath = url.Action(action, controller, routeValueDictionary);
```

But I get the same error, so I know the problem is not the conversion from `object` to `RouteValueDictionary`.

what am I missing here?

EDIT:

The extension is actually working when I use it in a view. I get the exception when I'm calling this from a new UrlHelper in a service class. Why do I get this exception?

Comment: If you just want to get an absolute URL, you can already so this with the `Url.Action` method - just specify the scheme.

Comment: do you mean with `Request.Url.Scheme`? Can you take into account the port like that?

Comment: Yes, with that. The `Url.Action` method will just whatever the current host is, including the port.

Comment: Thanks, this is useful to know; but I'm getting the same exception when I do this in the controller:
`var x = Action("action", "controller", new { id = "deneme" }, ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.Scheme`. The same ArgumentNullException is: `Value cannot be null. Parameter name: routeCollection`

I'm really lost, why am I getting this exception?

Comment: oh boy, my extension is actually working, I get the exception because I was calling this from a controller. I still don't understand why I get the exception though.

Comment: now I try using this in a service class, still can't get it to work anywhere other than the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok solved this. In case anybody needs to do this: the problem was not in the extension method but in the way I called it. I was instantiating a new `UrlHelper` with the default constructor, but I needed to use the constructor that takes the `requestContext`.

So if you want to use this in a controller, construct `UrlHelper` with:

`var url = new UrlHelper(Request.RequestContext);`

and in a seperate class:

`var url = new UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext);`